# How come the 'height' of my linear-gradient diminishes over time in Safari?

Tags: css

I use a `linear-gradient` as a count-down indicator for my application, and it works pretty much as expected in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari. The problem is that the 'height' of the gradient seems to diminish over time, as can be seen from the video that I captured on my phone (Safari on iOS):

[image: Example from Safari on my iPhone]

```js
(function updateCounter() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    document.getElementById("counter").classList.remove("reset");
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      document.getElementById("counter").classList.add("reset");
    });
  });
  document.getElementById("counter").addEventListener("animationend", updateCounter);
})();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 25%;
}

#counter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(#fa6400, #fa6400);
  background-position: left;
  background-size: 100%, 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #191932;
}

.reset {
  animation: counter 15s linear;
}

@keyframes counter {
  0% {
    background-size: 100%, 100%;
  }

  100% {
    background-size: 0%, 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="counter"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the animation starts off as expected but quickly devolves into a total mess after a while. I have tried to wrap my head around the issue for some time now, however, I cannot figure out what the underlying issue could be. Am I doing something out of the ordinary with my CSS? Any hint you might have as to how I would tackle this issue is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: did you prefixed your code? https://autoprefixer.github.io/

Comment: I did not prefix my code. Actually, I did not even know that this was a thing. Thank you for the heads up, @Ifaruki. This will surely be helpful in the future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears there's a simple syntax mistake. In the places you define the `background-size` values, you use `100%, 100%`, or `0%, 100%` - both which include a comma.

This syntax (with a comma) is for defining multiple backgrounds. In your case you want to define a single background, with separate width and height. To do this, remove the comma so your values are `100% 100%`, `0% 100%`, etc.

With your current syntax, you're telling it to transition both the height and width from 100% to 0%, which is resulting in the weirdness you're seeing. What you want to do is transition the width from 100% to 0%, and keep the height at 100%.

Like this:

```js
(function updateCounter() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    document.getElementById("counter").classList.remove("reset");
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      document.getElementById("counter").classList.add("reset");
    });
  });
  document.getElementById("counter").addEventListener("animationend", updateCounter);
})();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 25%;
}

#counter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(#fa6400, #fa6400);
  background-position: left;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #191932;
}

.reset {
  animation: counter 15s linear;
}

@keyframes counter {
  0% {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }

  100% {
    background-size: 0% 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="counter"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, Brett! This solved the issue, and I feel a little ashamed for not seeing that myself. Anyway, I will award you the bounty as soon as I can :)